# File shareing on Android 13

Tags: android, file-sharing

I have written an Android app with AndroidStudio, which create configuration files in JSON format, which are saved on device and can be shared.

Before Android 12 this worked without any problems. With Android 12 I got problems with saving the files but shareing still worked. I was able to fix saving by using a subdirectory at Documents instead of app's directory. Fixed saving works also on Android 13. But on Android 13 sharing via Outlook does no longer work (Unable to add attachment). With Teams it still can be shared.

The files are shared with this code:

```
//File file is selected by user
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email"); //I tried it also with "*/*"
emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent , "Share..."));
```

Does anyone know a reason why shareing via Outlook does no longer work or does anyone know an example app, which is able to share self created and saved JSON files on Android 13?

---

After first response I defined a FileProvider in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.test.project.fileProvider"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_provider_path"/>
</provider>
```

Additionally, I added file_provider_path.xml to res/xml with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path
        name="external_files"
        path="."/>
</paths>
```

And I changed code for getting Uri to

```
File file = new File(getCacheDir(), "testfile.json");
//... content is written with BufferedWriter    
Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.test.example.fileProvider", file);
//Uri then is content://com.test.project.fileProvider/external_files/testfile.json
```

Thank you for any help and kind regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: You cannot use Uri.fromFile() to build an uri. That should not have worked on Android 12- too.  Use FileProvider to get an uri and serve your file. All has nothing to do with Outlook. Your setType() is strange too.

Comment: I added a FileProvider as shown in "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41mC3UzpdeI" and FileProvider.getUriForFile() returns a Uri like "content://com.test.project.fileProvider/external_files/file.json" but I get still the same error. Any further ideas?

Comment: "testfile.json" wil never change to "file.json". please post your new code in one code block.

Comment: Also you should add a file.exists() snd file.canRead() to your code before using the file provider.

Comment: Since I create the file explicite for sharing I was quite sure that it exists. For verification I added file.exists() and file.canRead(), which returns both true

Comment: Add it to your code block. Show what you do. One code block please with all code. And change setType().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I created a very example Android app, which creates a file and implements sharing this file with FileProvider: [SharingTestApp](https://github.com/hobber89/SharingTestApp) I hope this example helps others to implement file sharing